# Specify Image Height and Width in php string

Tags: php, html, image, socialengine

I have a linked image that I need to specify height and width html attributes for that is generated by php string. I've looked into using getimagesize but its not looking like what I need. I am currently using social engine.

This is the string I have that calls the image link.

`<?php echo $this->htmlLink($item->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($item, 'null'), array('class' => '')) ?>`

which outputs html somthing like `<a href="#"><img src="#" class="null"/></a>`

I need to modify the php to create an image that is specified to be 110px x 110px
ie `<a href="#"><img src="#" class="null" width="110" height="110"/></a>`

Can anyone give me an example of how I could write my string?

Comment: You're using functions from a framework. What framework are you using?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=nb&q=image+resize+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: Agree. Which framework are you using Mike?

Comment: I've edited my question and added framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink(
    $item->getHref(), 
    $this->itemPhoto(
        $item, 
        'null', 
        null, 
        array('width' => '110px', 'height' => '110px')), 
    array('class' => '')
) ?>
```

That is, add a fourth parameter array to `itemPhoto` function.

Socialengine is an extension of Zend framework. You should try to check out the definition of `itemPhoto`, `htmlLink` etc. functions in order to customize them. For example `itemPhoto` can be found here- \application\modules\Core\View\Helper\ItemPhoto.php

Comment: Comes thru!!!! +1000 rep if it was possible. Your solution has worked beautifully. I will also take a look at the functions now that i knoow where to look. Thanks a million Salman

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter is used for that, isn't that?

```
$this->htmlLink(
  $item->getHref(), 
  $this->itemPhoto($item, '', '', array('width' => 110, 'height' => 110)),
  array('class' => '')
);
```

Comment: Not quite, this added height and width to the link attibute, not the image.

Comment: @MikeM So how about the `itemPhoto` method?

Comment: @MikeM The framework you are using seems not opensource, so it's hard to tell without read the source.

Comment: I do believe it is based on zend framework... social engine has been more than troublesome when It comes to scaling.

Comment: @MikeM OK, after do something searching, the result come out. check my edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11560/discussion-between-xdazz-and-mike-m)

Answer (score 1):

**Method1:**
Just add style for null class

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink($item->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($item, 'null'), array('class' => '')) ?>
```

as:

```
.null {
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
}
```

---

**Method2:**
Or you can pass a inline style attribute as:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink($item->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($item, 'null'), array('class' => '', 'style' => 'height: 110px; width: 110px')) ?>
```

Comment: Your method 2 looks like it is just about working, for some reason it is adding style attribute to the link html and not the image html.

Comment: I've already got css dimensions for the images. I'm attempting to follow pagespeed insights to further optimize my site. One performance recommendation was to serve scaled images by changing the html.

Comment: Okay, what about @xdazz's modified solution, is that working? I found no docs for this `itemPhoto()` method.

Comment: No unfortunately still no luck. Thanks again for your help @Vishal

Answer (score 0):

I cant see whats behind the function htmlLink() but I guess due to the name of those elements you pass you could just write.

```
echo '<a href="'.$item->getHref().'"><img src="'.$this->itemPhoto($item, 'null').'" class="null" width="110" height="110"/></a>';
```

but ether post that function or just try and error!

Comment: I think that is my problem, I cannot seem to get down to the function behind htmlLink() myself. I thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome, try to get your head deeper into the classes of that framework, the code above is just a workaround.

Comment: I will do that. Even though I cant accomplish my objective, I have still learned something new. Thanks again for your help @systrue

Comment: dont know your php level, but this helps to get an overview, since frameworks can be confusing at first. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/